# Lazarus : How to import data from a textfile into a table?

Tags: dataframe, import, lazarus

I got a textfile that contains data in column format, separated by `;` (origin of this file is a dataframe created with R and saved as a textfile).

```
 Name; Date; Results; Score;
 John; 1; 100; 1
 John; 3 ; 200; 1
 John; 5; 30; 9
 Mike; 1; 90; 2
 Mike; 3; 34; 10
 Mike; 5; 216; 1
 ...
```

I would like to import these dataframe into tables declared in Lazarus. 
This is what I started to do :

```
  Type
 TRunning=record
 Date, Score: array [1..3] of integer; ## since I have 3 datas per name
 Results: array [1..3] of double;
   Var
 Run : array [1..100] of TRunning ## since I have a total of 100 names
```

Could you help me to do import data from the textfile?

Answer (score 2):

use `TStringList.LoadFromFile()` it creat  `stringlist` form evry row in your file, then
extract colomn strings from your data using `ExtractStrings :`

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);    
      var
          rowlist,collist:TStringList;
          i:integer
        begin
             rowlist:=TStringList.Create;
             collist:=TStringList.Create;
             rowlist.LoadFromFile('filename');
             for i:=0 to rowlist.Count-1 do
             begin 
                ExtractStrings([';'],[''],PChar(rowlist.Strings[i]),collist);
                //fill your table with  collist
             end;
        end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ExtractString function. But how do I fill my table using the "collist" stringlist? (this a the step that I had the most difficulty to achieve)

Comment: what do you mean by table? do you mean StringGrid?

Comment: I mean the arrays declared in my record

Comment: For example, I would like to get access to the value of the 2nd run (ie 2nd name) corresponding to the 3rd date, by typing :
Run[2].Date[3]

Comment: you can use</br> Run[2].Date[3]:=collist.Strings[i]